# Node.js program not ending

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, sharp

I wrote a node.js program and it is not ending after doing everything.

I tried everything.

Below is my code :

```
const log = require('why-is-node-running') // should be your first require
const net = require('net')

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//const sharp = require("sharp");

const sharp = require("sharp");

 async function tkscr() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // set the size of the viewport, so our screenshot will have the desired size
  await page.setViewport({
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080
})


  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', {waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0});
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'gg.jpeg' ,fullPage: true});

  await browser.close();

  
}

tkscr().then(
  res => cropImage())
  .catch(err => console.log(err)); 

   function cropImage() {
    try {
       sharp("gg.jpeg")
        .extract({ width: 770, height: 388, left: 552, top: 770  })
        .toFile("sammy.jpeg", function(err) {
          console.log("process completed");
          setTimeout(function () {
            log() // logs out active handles that are keeping node running
          }, 100)
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

this app take screenshot with puppeteer and then use sharp to crop the screenshot

I use 'why-is-node-running'

I got the log below:

[image]

I don't know what I should do? please help me

thanks

Comment: When removing the `setTimeout` with the `log` the program just ends perfectly fine for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i test out the program it ends correctly. Remove the `log()` and it just stops as expected..

```
const log = require('why-is-node-running') // should be your first require
const net = require('net')

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

//const sharp = require("sharp");

const sharp = require("sharp");

async function tkscr() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // set the size of the viewport, so our screenshot will have the desired size
    await page.setViewport({
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    })


    await page.goto('https://www.google.com/', { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 0 });
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'gg.jpeg', fullPage: true });
    await browser.close();


}

tkscr().then(
    res => cropImage())
    .catch(err => console.log('catch err:', err));

async function cropImage() {
    try {
        sharp("gg.jpeg")
            .extract({ width: 770, height: 388, left: 552, top: 770 })
            .toFile("sammy.jpeg", function (err) {
                console.log('everything done.')
            })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

The `why-is-node-running` module shows dead handles which may not have been "garbage collected" yet since node decided to do it later, so it's more confusing then something else in this script.